# TextView autoSizeTextType not working in Compat

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-support-library

I tried using `autoSizeTextType`. 
My **minSdk** is 24, all the **tools** are 26 and **compat** ist 26-beta2 as well.

Making them adjustable was tried through code:

```
dialogWeight.touchables.filterIsInstance<Button>().forEach {
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(it, 
TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM) }
```

And xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="7"
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

Any ideas ? I'm starting to believe that it's currently bugged

Answer (score 19):

Okay, so the combination of settings that worked :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
android:text="7"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

You also need the appcompat-v7 library as a dependency in your module build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Could you also please post the relevant contents of your build.gradle that includes the compatibility bits as I'm having trouble getting this working. Also, does the Android Studio editor show any error on the `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` line? And are you able to address the `AppCompatTextView` as a `TextView` programatically?

Comment: I also have the same issue. To use the `AppCompatTextView` and `TextViewCompat` properly, you should include support-v4 (com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1) and appcompat-v7 (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1) to your build gradle. Make sure to change your `<TextView/>` xml tag into `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView/>`.
Hope It can be any help for you :)

Comment: @nanangarsyad appcompat-v7 installs support-v4 as a dependency. You only need appcompat-v7 in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Side note, make sure not to set `android:singleLine="true"`, then the auto-shrink will not work. Also set `autoSizeMinTextSize`, otherwise a default value seems to be applied and the text could be cut off at the end.

Answer (score 12):

The key thing to understand is to use **`app:autoSizeTextType`**, as opposed to **`android:autoSizeTextType`**

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview):

> To define the default setting in XML through the support library, use the **app namespace** and set the autoSizeTextType attribute to none or uniform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

I solved it programmatically.

```java
TextView number1 = findViewById(R.id.number_one);
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(number1, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
```

and the XML:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_one"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"  />
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to update this thread since android.support.v7 has been migrated to androidX

I was having problems getting the text to display at all and what fixed it for me was this note about singleLine in one of the comments:

> > Side note, make sure not to set android:singleLine="true", then the auto-shrink will not work.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tempText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20dp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        tools:text="99&#xb0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

These days with androidx you want to use `implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"` along with TewxtView and e.g. `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`