# Is there a limitation in length of TextView

Tags: android, textview, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm developing Android App and I'amm putting some strings that reach 20,653Bytes in TextView.

When I build and execute on API 22 device, it works. However, When building on API 26 device, IndexOutOfBoundsException error occured like below.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class TextView
                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class TextView
                      Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

How to solve this error? I have to display this text at at time.

Comment: can u show the XML you are using for the textview in question

Comment: Have you tried setting android:maxLength="25000" on the TextView? I've read that some phones have a maximum of 9000 though it leads to truncation not crashes...

Comment: @Elletlar Though I set that property, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah okay. The index out of bounds exception suggests they are fixing the size. But if that's the case the data should be truncated, crashing is a defect...My phone is 26, I'll see if I can reproduce it. Cheers.

Comment: Also, can you not use multiple TextViews? I display large logs in one of my apps though I implemented it using a Listview with each line in the logs having its own Textview. With the adapter, there are only a handful of TextViews in memory at any one time...

Comment: @Elletlar the layout that caused error has three TextViews. Just one TextView has many texts.

Comment: It might make your problem worst, but you could try AppCompatTextView. This post shows how to use it [AppCompatTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059411/textview-autosizetexttype-not-working-in-compat)

Comment: @Elletlar I tried AppCompatTextView. But it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved like below.

Save text(formed in html) in String variable, and then,

```
    tvContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(html1));
```

When I just used strings.xml, it didn't work.