# autoSize TextView not working (targeting v.24 with androidx)

Tags: android, androidx

I've looked up the previous questions, but none are using the modern androidx versions of the dependencies. Why is the TextView not automatically resizing the text? I've specified the required dependencies (appcompat and legacy-support).

It works if I use `android:autoSizeMaxTextSize` instead of `app:`, but that requires API level 26 and I'm targeting 24. `app:` used to be the fallback method before androidx; has that changed?

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testprogram"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

and my `activity.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#330000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTimer1"
        android:layout_width="893dp"
        android:layout_height="415dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-27dp"
        android:alpha="0.25"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Test Text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="380sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="380sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should try this. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059614/6035923

Comment: The issue is appcompat-v7 is deprecated. It worked fine before, but when trying to convert it to use the androidx libraries the issue arose.